# Is this lens compatible?

Tags: lens, canon, compatibility, vivitar

Will a Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 MC Lens fit my Canon Rebel t7i or do I need some type of connector?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange - Vivitar make lenses for many different camera models, and whether it is a "Canon" version is not readily obvious from the descriptions. Could you please add photos of both ends of the lens, in particular showing the connectors on the "camera side" of the lens, the clever folks here can probably help.

Comment: Thank You so much for the information. I saw it very cheap on sale and wondered if it would work with my camera. I still need to learn my camera; I really don't need to worry about lenses!!!

Answer (score 0):

The Vivitar 75-205mm 1:3.8 MC Lens is an older film era, manual focus lens, and is not a direct fit for your Canon T7i.

You could use that lens if you have the correct adapter. That lens was made in many different camera mounts. You will need to identify which camera mount it has so you can buy the correct adapter.

Because it is a manual focus, manual aperture lens, you will probably find it difficult to use, even with the correct adapter.

The image quality from this lens will not be as good as what we have come to expect from modern lenses. It will be further degraded if the adapter uses an additional optical element as needed with some mounts.

See also [“Can my Canon 5D work with this Vivitar lens”](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/129715/can-my-canon-eos-5d-clasic-work-with-vivitar-lens?rq=1)

Comment: Thank You so much Mike!!!